# Projections of uniform distributions on high-dimensional geometric objects

Tags: geometry, probability-theory

Consider a uniform distribution $\mathbb{P}_N$ on the $N$- dimensional Ball  $\Omega_N = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^N \mid ||x||^2 \le vN \}$ with radius $\sqrt{vN}$. For some $n \le N$, let $X_n$ be the projection on the $n$-th coordinate, then
$ \mathbb{P}_N(a\le X_n \le b) $ approaches a normal distribution with variance $v$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$.

Are there similar results for other geometric objects?

For example, if we replace the Ball by an $N$- dimensional ellipsoid the variance of the resulting normal distribution results in $v$ scaled by the coefficient of the considered coordinate in the ellipsoid equation.

Comment: Yes, if you consider an orthogonally aligned  cube the projection will also be uniform :D

Comment: But more seriously, are you interested in the method of determining the probability distribution of the projection of arbitrary shape given its infinite scaling? Or are you looking for very specific shapes for which this probability is "nice"?

Comment: Kind of both. Up until now I'm only aware of the explicit construction for the above problem for a single coordinate, I saw in class, and using CLT. 
For, now i would be happy you could point out how one would in general try to determine such an asymptotic distribution. This interplay of geometry, analysis and proabability caught my attention :)